# CSOM does not use windows credential and giving "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I have a console application with .NET Framework which uploads a file using CSOM. When I run the application I get below error:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

However, When I pass my windows credential it works fine. I don't want to hardcode my credential in code due to security purpose. Is there any work around except passing credential in the code?

My code is as below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using ClientOM = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;


namespace ConsoleApp3
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://companyname.sharepoint.com");

        //SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
        //foreach (char c in "HelloWorld@1234".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
        //clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("jay.desai@company.com", passWord);
        clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\jay.desai\Desktop\LSRSQL01_ACXM_20201003.html", FileMode.Open))
            ClientOM.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, "/sites/DataServices/Shared Documents/Data Dictionaries/LSRSQL01_ACXM_20201003.html", fileStream, true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: With Default Credentials the user need the same Windows account on both local and remote machine.  So the two machines need to be in the same Group (or Group Policy) so both machines a using the same Password Server for the user account.

Comment: @jdweng, yes both have same password and user account. I am using same username and password to login to my local system as well as share point or office 365.

Comment: That is not what I asked.  The two machines need to be linked.  Having the same username and password doesn't mean it is the same account.

Comment: Like other comments mention both machine and target need to be in same AD, also possible there's an MFA step for authentication.

Comment: Is there any alternative to `clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;` except hardcoding username and password?

Answer (score 0):

CSOM connect SharePoint Online requires SharePointOnlineCredentials.
Test demo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)   
      {  
            string userName = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";  
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your password.");  
            SecureString password = GetPassword();                  
            using(var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://contoso.sharepoint.com"))   
            {  
                // SharePoint Online Credentials  
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);  
                // Get the SharePoint web  
                Web web = clientContext.Web;  
                // Load the Web properties  
                clientContext.Load(web);  
                // Execute the query to the server.  
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  
                // Web properties - Display the Title and URL for the web  
                Console.WriteLine("Title: " + web.Title + "; URL: " + web.Url);  
                Console.ReadLine();  
                }  
            } 

private static SecureString GetPassword()  
      {  
            ConsoleKeyInfo info;  
            //Get the user's password as a SecureString  
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();  
            do   
            {  
                info = Console.ReadKey(true);  
                if (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)   
                {  
                    securePassword.AppendChar(info.KeyChar);  
                }  
            }  
            while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);  
            return securePassword;  
        }
```

Source:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-sharepoint-2013-online-using-csom-with-console-ap/

Updated:

```
string siteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/demo";
using (var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, "[Your Client ID]", "[Your Client Secret]"))
{
    cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
};
```

Comment: You could hard-code the password.var pwd = "mypassword";
var passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@mydomain.com", passWord);

Comment: That’s already I was doing. If you see my code I have commented it. I don’t want to hardcode and that’s the whole point of putting this post on stack overflow.

Comment: Emmm,you could access SharePoint Online with SharePoint App.Official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs